# storing cookies and retrieving them in the html form values using php

Tags: php, html, cookies

hi friends i have created a form as below and tried to set cookies for every-field, i succeed in setting cookies for the input text boxes, but i failed to do the same for textarea fields and for drop-down list as well as for check-boxes. The form is as below....

```
<input name="date" type="text" size="10" value="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE["date"])) echo $_COOKIE["date"];?>" onblur="setCookie(this.name,this.value,60*60*2)" /></td>
          Order Number:
          <input name="order_num" type="text" size="10" value="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE["order_num"])) echo $_COOKIE["order_num"];?>" onblur="setCookie(this.name,this.value,60*60*2)" />
         First Name:
          <td><input name="fname" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE["fname"])) echo $_COOKIE["fname"];?>" onblur="setCookie(this.name,this.value,60*60*2)"/></td>
          Last Name:
          <td><input name="lname" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE["lname"])) echo $_COOKIE["lname"];?>" onblur="setCookie(this.name,this.value,60*60*2)"/>

          Image Submitted:
          <input name="image" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE["image"])) echo $_COOKIE["image"];?>" onblur="setCookie(this.name,this.value,60*60*2)"/>
          General Comments:
         <textarea name="gen_comments" cols="50" rows="6"  onblur="setCookie(this.name,text,60*60*2)" ><?php if(isset($_COOKIE["gen_comments"])) { echo $_COOKIE["gen_comments"];}?></textarea>

          Internal Comments:
          <textarea name="int_comments" cols="50" rows="6" onblur="setCookie(this.name,text,60*60*2)"><?php if(isset($_COOKIE["int_comments"])) { echo $_COOKIE["int_comments"];}?></textarea>
         Quality of the File:
           <select name="quality" onchange="" >
           <option >Select One</option><option name="good" value="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE["good"])) echo $_COOKIE["good"];?>">Good</option><option value="ok">A bit low but we can use it</option><option value="low">Low. We are concerned it might effect the qaulity of the final</option><option value="not good">Not good. We cannot work with it</option><option value="test2">test2</option><option value="test">test</option><option value="lkdjfalkdjlaksjdla dlkajsdaksjdlkajsdlkjaslkdjas alksdjaslkdjlaksjdla">Lisa1</option><option value="bbb">aaa</option>        <!--option value="good">Good</option>
           <option value="ok">A bit low but we can use it</option>
           <option value="low">Low. We are concerned it might effect the qaulity of the final </option>
           <option value="not good">Not good. We can't work with it</option-->
            </select> 
          <input type="button" name="qofoption" id="qofoption" value="Add New Option" 
          onClick="optionWindow('http://www.lightaffection.com/Hema2/addnewoption.php?option=qof','optionwindow','400','200')"/>        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><div name="qofdiv"></div></tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right">Image Proportions and Content:</td>
          <td colspan="2" style="padding-right:4px">
           <select name="imageprop" id="imageprop">
           <option>Select One</option><option value="test2">test2</option><option value="not good">Too much details for a Night Light</option><option value="good">Good</option><option value="test">test</option><option value="asdas">asdsa</option><option value="bbb">bbb</option>
          <td><b>How would you like us to proceed?</b></td><td></td></tr>

         <input type="checkbox" name="proceed_opt[]" value="I will upload new Image">
              Insert Option &quot;I will upload new Image&quot;</td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td colspan="2">
                &nbsp; 
              <input type="checkbox" name="proceed_opt[]" value="I approve this sample for a Night Light">
              Insert Option &quot;<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">I approve this sample for a Night Light</font>&quot; </td></tr><tr><td></td><td colspan="2">
                &nbsp; 
              <input type="checkbox" name="proceed_opt[]" value="Select One">
              Insert Option &quot;<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">Select One</font>&quot; </td></tr>     
         <tr><td></td><td colspan='2'> &nbsp;
         <input type="checkbox" name="proceed_opt[]" value="other">
              Insert Option &quot;Other See comments&quot;</td></tr>

          <td> Ship by date: <input name="shipdate" type="text" /><br />
          <br />
          Update Order Status to: <select name="orderstatus">
            <option>Do not change</option>
            <option>Waiting for designer</option>
            <option>Waiting for customer response</option>
          </select>
          <br />
          <input name="ordermanager" type="checkbox" value="" /> Update Order Manager <br />
          <input name="createhtml" type="checkbox" value="" /> Create an HTML page <br />
          <input name="sendemail" type="checkbox" value="" /> Send Email to Customer <br />      </td>


    </form>
```

thanks in advance..

Comment: Can I ask why you want a cookie for every field?

Comment: Also browser from browser have some restrictions about how many cookies You can set.. FF has 40, IE 30 I think... Take this into count...

Comment: @MrD just for the convenience i'm doing this. please help me out in setting the cookies for the remaining fields in the form..

Comment: No idea what you're doing, but HTML5 local storage might be relevant. http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Comment: @abc123 Can you not store all the data in one cookie and separate values with for instance a +, as this will just get messy and end up being more inconvenient?

Comment: @MrD ok dude actually i don't know how to implement that method...can u show me how to do that to store & set cookies for all the fields in my form..

Comment: @abc123 see my answer personally I would use my second suggest, add a comment to my answer if you want me to explain either in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Simple example on how to set/read/delete cookies with PHP:

```
<?php

// set a cookie
setcookie("cookiename", "cookievalue", time()+3600);

// read a cookie
if (isset($_COOKIE["cookiename"])) {
  $mycookievalue = $_COOKIE["cookiename"];
}

// delete a cookie
setcookie("cookiename", "", time()-3600);

?>
```

*To your practical case, just repeat for every field you need to store.*

**e.g.,**

```
<?php
foreach($_POST as $key =>$value) {
  setcookie($key, $value, time()+3600);
}
?>
```

---

## KNOW MORE

**The cookie Syntax:**

```
setcookie(name, value, expire, path, domain);
```

**Where can you read about this:**

[W3C - PHP Cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp)

[PHP.net Cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php)

[PHP Cookies Tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpcookies.php)

Comment: how to implement this for the textarea, drop-down & check box fields in my form?

Comment: Just added an example for you, see the e.g.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, although there are better ways to do this:

PHP cookies must be set before the headers are sent(before any output is given, so you could not set them as you wish)

You are left with the following choices:

```
 -set the cookies using javascript
 -Create a file which acts as the forms action, and in that file pull all the $_POST values and set them there.
```

But again I repeat, there are better ways to do this.

Comment: i can't do that kind of thing in my page as these cookies should work not on the page submission or something like that..after filling each field the cookie should be set and that cookie value should be repeated even after the page is re-loaded

Comment: What is your end goal? What are you trying to use these cookies for?

Comment: after setting all the field values once in the form and once the page reloads all the fields should retain the values in the cookies of that form.

Comment: The fields must be being saved to some sort of db so pull the values from there?

Comment: no all the fields must have cookies and have to use them when the page reloads

Comment: If you know indepth javascript and the jQuery and AJAX framework, look in to setting the cookie using that. If not I would set them in the form action 'submit.php' using  foreach($_POST as $key =>$value) {
  setcookie($key, $value, whatevertime); }

Comment: I have to reiterate @MrD's question - why does it have to be cookies? If you can explain that we might be able to help you with the best solution. There are other options that are more convenient, use better logic, and don't run the risk of broswer restrictions or people who have cookies turned off.

Comment: hi @FluffyKitten i have made some adjustments in my code, here i succeed in getting cookies for the input text fields,help me out in setting the cookies in the similar way for the remaining fields like textarea's,check-boxes and drop-down lists...

Comment: Are your problems with the cookie code or dynamically setting values for form elements? You need to edit your question with details of the exact problems & errors because its not clear. Also, store your cookie values in variables & use the variables in the form to make it much easier to follow e.g.`<?php if(isset($_COOKIE["image"])) { $image = $_COOKIE["image"];} //etc ?>` and `<input name="image" type="text" value="<?=$image?>...>" But that isn't the point either @MrD or I was making - you haven't explained why you're using so many cookies, it is a bad solution.

Comment: Hmm should you not use a session to store values between pages?

Comment: @PeteStorey A numboer of other (better) solutions have been suggested,  but its just not getting through :)